# laravel - Redirect back to login page after successful login in live server

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

It performed good in localhost but when i test in live server site in admin panel it redirect to login panel  after successful login .. firstly goto home page then without entering to home it redirect back url to login url.

I research every sector but not find my solutions.

Lastly,I found it redirect from vendor/symfony.../httpfondation/redirctresponse.php

guys can you help me to find out this error.

Comment: can you share your login code? and routes ?

Comment: everything is good but there is problem in redirecting in live server.. it cant store user variables in session..

Comment: what do you mean by redirecting to Live server ? from where you redirecting to where ?

Comment: Dude, you need to elaborate with the relevant code otherwise it is almost impossible to help you out.